# Translating "Loading..." word from JS file in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, internationalization

When i click on Grid to view my list items then there is message "Loading..." shows up during the loading of the items into the Grid. I want to translate this "Loading..." word into french but i cant do it because its linked in .Js file.

How can i translate this word???
 in my file **grid-locale-en.js**

```
(function(a){a.jgrid={defaults:{recordtext:"View {0} - {1} of {2}",emptyrecords:"No records to view",loadtext:"Loading...",pgtext:"Page {0} of {1}"},......)
```

Can anybody help me plzz

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need some client-side localization.

There are many plugins to handle just that:

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/i18n

Comment: thanks @Arnaud, Yes i have doing client side localizaion, i have been using this above mention plugin but its work for .html.erb or .rb files. I have to do it in my .js file. If you have got my point then plez let me know its solution

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:
[I18n in Javascript files with Rails 3](http://ggomeze.com/2011/10/10/i18n-in-javascript-files-with-rails-3).

Ger

Answer (score 0):

as you say you have a file called grid-locale-en.js
is this something you made yourself, or is this part of the framework.

if it is the latter, i assume you could just go ahead and make a  grid-locale-fr.js for french for example? translate all strings in there.

however this is just my assumption on the file name you already use.

Answer (score 0):

It may make sense to put the javascript translations inline into your javascript (if you only have a couple ones).

```
var loading_trans = <%= t :loading %>;
```